# Удалить класс у элемента на чистом javascript

Tags: javascript

Не работает удаление класса на чистом js.

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  var showPizza = document.getElementById('showPizza');
  var pizza = document.getElementsByClassName('pizza');

  showPizza.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    pizza.className.remove('hide');
  });

  console.log('get to the choppa!!!');
});
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <a id="showPizza" href="javascript:void(0);">Pizza Time</a>
  <div class="pizza hide">
    <img src="img/pizza1.gif" alt="pizza" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Выдает ошибку `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'remove' of undefined`. В чем ошибка?

Comment: className -> classList

Comment: А в переменной pizza массив из элементов, а не элемент

Comment: так тоже делала, та же ошибка

Comment: в блоке `pizza` находится одна `img`

Comment: Я не про блок, а про переменную js, это массив из блоков.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  var showPizza = document.getElementById('showPizza');
  var pizza = document.getElementsByClassName("pizza")[0];
  console.log(pizza.className);

  showPizza.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    pizza.classList.remove('hide');
    console.log(pizza.className)
  });


});
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <a id="showPizza" href="javascript:void(0);">Pizza Time</a>
  <div class="pizza hide">
    <img src="img/pizza1.gif" alt="pizza" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: так всегда надо писать `[0]` ? если там будет много элементов?

Comment: @MarinaVoronova пройтись циклом по всему массиву, очевидно

Comment: смотря к какому элементу массива вы хотите пременить ту или иную функцию..

Comment: чтобы пройтись по всему массиву , нужно точно указать его количество? как то так, например? `[0-15]` ? а если точное количество элементов не известно?

Comment: while(); https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/while

Answer (score 0):

Пробуйте так:

```
var pizza = document.getElementsByClassName('pizza')[0];
```

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  var showPizza = document.getElementById('showPizza');
  var pizza = document.getElementsByClassName('pizza')[0];

  showPizza.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    
    
    console.log(pizza);
    pizza.classList.remove('hide');
  });

  console.log('get to the choppa!!!');
});
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <a id="showPizza" href="javascript:void(0);">Pizza Time</a>
  <div class="pizza hide">
    <img src="img/pizza1.gif" alt="pizza" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -4):

Привет!

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  document.getElementById('showPizza').addEventListener('click', function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      document.getElementsByClassName('pizza')[0].className.remove('hide');
  });
console.log('get to the choppa!!!');
});
```

Убрал переменные и всё заработало. Почему? А потому, что когда ты пишешь в переменную например:

```
var pizza = document.getElementsByClassName('pizza')[0];
```

то у тебя скрипт делает из pizza ссылку на

```
document.getElementsByClassName('pizza')[0]
```

Обращаясь к pizza ты можешь редактировать то, на что pizza является ссылкой, то бишь скрипты:
pizza.innerHTML
и
document.getElementsByClassName('pizza')[0].innerHTML
вернут идентичный результат.

UPD:
Переменная showPizza у Вас определилась автоматически, т.к. вы дали элементу id=showPizza. Можете смело обращаться к этой переменной без вызовов метода document.getElementById(...).

Comment: Нет, не копирует, а создаёт ссылку на те же самые данные. Просто в вопросе `[0]` отсутствует. Ответ неверный

Comment: @andreymal помилуйте! у меня всё работает!

Comment: Из работоспособности не обязательно следует верность ответа, вы там бред понаписали, никаких данных не копируется